# Enviar datos del formulario al controlador al ser correctos - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mvc

Tengo una función en *JavaScript* que *chekea* si hay *inputs* vacíos `onkeyup`. Si los hay me avisa con un `alert`, y también tengo una función que cuando pulsa el botón guardar, comprueba que dos campos ingresen la misma contraseña.

El problema está en que si yo dejo todos los campos vacíos y solo completo los campos para poner las mismas contraseñas y pulso el botón `Guardar`, me envía esos datos vacíos. Yo quiero que al pulsar el botón `Guardar` cumpla con la funciones de *JavaScript*.

Código completo:

```js
function comprobarClave() {

  validarCamposInput();

  clave1 = document.f1.txtClave1.value
  clave2 = document.f1.txtClave2.value

  if (clave1 != clave2)
    alert("Las dos contraseñas son distintas!.\nLas contraseñas deben ser iguales!")
  else
    document.f1.submit()//pulsa el submit y manda los datos del form

  //validarCamposInput();

  //Other Sentences
}

var mensajeCabecera = "Los siguientes campos están vacíos:\n";
var mensajeValidacion = "";

function validarCamposInput() {
  mensajeValidacion = "";

  $(".form-group > input").each(function () {
    if (this.value == "") {
      mensajeValidacion = mensajeValidacion + (this.id).replace("txt", "") + "\n";
      $("#" + this.id).addClass('bordeRojoValidacion');
    }
  });

  if (mensajeValidacion == "") {
    return;
  }
  else {
    alert(mensajeCabecera + mensajeValidacion);
  }
}
function validarInput(caracter) {
  if (caracter != "") {
    $("#" + caracter.id).removeClass('bordeRojoValidacion');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="f1">
  @using (Html.BeginForm("RegistrarUsuario", "Usser", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "f1" }))
  {
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lblUserName">Nombre de usuario:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtUsserName" name="txtUsserName" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" placeholder="UserName" maxlength="45">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lblPwd">Contraseña:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txtClave1" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" id="clave1" maxlength="45" placeholder="Clave1" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lblPwd">Repita la contraseña:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txtClave2" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" id="clave2" maxlength="45" placeholder="Clave2" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="lblDom">Domicilio:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" placeholder="Address" maxlength="45">
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="comprobarClave()">Guardar</button>
  }
</form>
```

Comment: te falta el event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo necesitas 2 cosas:

1. Hacer que `validarCamposInput()` devuelva *verdadero* o *falso*.
2. Ejecutar y verificar el resultado de `validarCamposInput()` antes de enviar el formulario.

```js
function comprobarClave() {
  clave1 = document.f1.txtClave1.value
  clave2 = document.f1.txtClave2.value

  if (clave1 != clave2)
    alert("Las dos contraseñas son distintas!.\nLas contraseñas deben ser iguales!")
  else if(validarCamposInput()) // Solo se enviará si los campos están bien
    document.f1.submit()//pulsa el submit y manda los datos del form

  //Other Sentences
}

var mensajeCabecera = "Los siguientes campos están vacíos:\n";
var mensajeValidacion = "";

function validarCamposInput() {
  mensajeValidacion = "";

  $(".form-group > input").each(function () {
    if (this.value == "") {
      mensajeValidacion = mensajeValidacion + (this.id).replace("txt", "") + "\n";
      $("#" + this.id).addClass('bordeRojoValidacion');
    }
  });

  if (mensajeValidacion == "") {
    // No hay mensaje de error, quiere decir que los campos están correctos
    // Devolver verdadero
    return true;
  }
  alert(mensajeCabecera + mensajeValidacion);
  // Hay error en los campos
  // Devolver falso
  return false;
}

function validarInput(caracter) {
  if (caracter != "") {
    $("#" + caracter.id).removeClass('bordeRojoValidacion');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="f1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lblUserName">Nombre de usuario:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtUsserName" name="txtUsserName" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" placeholder="UserName" maxlength="45">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lblPwd">Contraseña:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txtClave1" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" id="clave1" maxlength="45" placeholder="Clave1" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lblPwd">Repita la contraseña:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="txtClave2" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" id="clave2" maxlength="45" placeholder="Clave2" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="lblDom">Domicilio:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" onkeyup="return validarInput(this);" placeholder="Address" maxlength="45">
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="comprobarClave()">Guardar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Gracias Triby,pero al pulsar el botón Guardar con todos los datos completos, me sale un error diciendo que: column 'Nombre' cannot be null...eso pasa porque el boton guardar no esta funcionando como Submit ? y por lo tanto me envía los datos vacios?

Comment: No, eso no tiene que ver, el botón no necesariamente debe ser submit, porque la función es la que dispara el método submit del formulario que, a final de cuentas, es exactamente lo mismo. Entonces, al parecer tu problema ya no es en esta instancia, sino en el servidor, ¿es correcto?

Comment: Evidentemente si!, tenes alguna idea que puede ser?, ya que me dice que la column 'Nombre' cannot be null

Comment: Lo recomendable es que hagas una nueva pregunta y coloques el código importante: formulario y lo que sea que estés usando del lado del servidor para procesarlo. Si esta respuesta te sirvió, por favor márcala como aceptada. Gracias.

Comment: Aparentemente no me había actualizado los cambios así que cerré la ventana del navegador y volví a Iniciar el proyecto y ya no me tira ese error de la columna vacía